# Is there a way to return a readablestream as a response in sveltekit

Tags: web, youtube, sveltekit, ytdl

In my app (downloads user generated sounds from youtube and plays them) I'm using ytdl to download the sounds to the client and play them. i am unable to return the readablestream from ytdl as a response.

this is my current code

```js
    const readstream = await (await youtube(id)).read()
    console.log(readstream) // logs null
    return readstream
```

`youtube` function

```js
import { downloadFromInfo, getInfo, validateID } from 'ytdl-core'

async function youtube(url: string) {
    if(!validateID(id)) throw new Error("URL not valid")
    return downloadFromInfo(await getInfo(`https://youtu.be/${id}`))
}
```

but i get this error:

```
Invalid response from route /api/source/yt/[redacted].mp3: handler should return a Response object
Error: Invalid response from route /api/source/yt/[redacted].mp3: handler should return a Response object
    at render_endpoint ([redacted]/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/runtime/server/endpoint.js:47:10)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async resolve ([redacted]/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/runtime/server/index.js:354:17)
    at async respond ([redacted]/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/runtime/server/index.js:229:20)
    at async [redacted]/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/exports/vite/dev/index.js:444:22
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to respond with a stream in a Sveltekit server load function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74330190/how-to-respond-with-a-stream-in-a-sveltekit-server-load-function)