# SvelteKit: Change UI on incoming Post Request

Tags: post, notifications, client, svelte, sveltekit

Assume the following:

src/route/create/+server.ts:

```js
import { json } from "@sveltejs/kit";
import type { RequestHandler } from "./$types";

import { testStore } from "$lib/stores/testStore";

export const POST = (async ({ request }) => {
    console.log("POST REQUEST INCOMING");
    testStore.set("something") << THIS IS NOT WORKING AS EXPECTED
    return json({ message: "hi" });
}) satisfies RequestHandler;
```

Then, in some svelte component:

```js
testStore.subscribe((value) => {
        if (value) {
            console.log("Post request came in!");
        }
    });
```

When I perform a post request, I can see this part "POST REQUEST INCOMING", but the value of the store is not being updated.

In general, I want to do this: The client makes a request to some other Python backend. That backend does something which takes maybe 10 seconds. Once Python is done, it sends a POST request back to the client (the /create endpoint from above), basically saying that the process is complete. Then the client is supposed to change its UI, notifying the user.

Any idea how I can do this?

I've already tried the code above, which didn't work...

Comment: Stores don't magically transfer data to the UI, they are separate objects that live on the server which usually makes it completely pointless to use them there. You either need multiple requests if you want multiple updates that get fed data from the server or a [stream](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74330190/546730). In most scenarios that is not even necessary, though, if you just want to show something like "please wait" you can do that before sending the request, wait for the response and update the UI then.